# Smooth Scrubbing video in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-mediacodec

I am trying to achieve smooth video scrubbing with Android `VideoView`. The `seekTo` method of `MediaPlayer` is not doing exactly what i want. It does not exactly seek to millisecond i passed in it, it actually plays from/jumps to the nearest position, not the exact I seeked to. Also the frames are showing with a large gaps. Not the exact frame for millisecond.

I came on searching around and found that `SEEK_CLOSEST_SYNC` can only seek to the nearest sync frame not the EXACT. It depends on the way the video was generated.
How can i achieve the smooth scrubbing and seek to exact position Even video is paused or playing. Is it possible through Android `VideoView` or `MediaPlayer` class or should i change the approach?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a straight forward question to answer. I spent a month researching and implementing it myself.

The only way this can be achieved is using [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec).

You can look at [this](https://github.com/protyposis/MediaPlayer-Extended) project that does exact scrubbing using `MediaCodec`. The only issue I had with that project is that it takes time to load the buffer and display it on the surface, about 0.5 seconds.

You can also have a look at [Grafica](https://github.com/google/grafika), especially the `MoviePlayer` class. Another source is the [BigFlake](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) website.

What I ended up doing is creating my own implementation using `MediaCodec` as none of them provided me exactly what I was looking for, as I was building a golf analyzer, I needed (real-time) precise (frame-per-frame) scrubbing of the video.

You can also look at a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036704/mediacodec-handle-video-with-dropped-frames) I asked that is similar to this, where I added a lot of info on how I achieved this. Though this question is more about playing a video frame-per-frame, I think there is valuable info in it.